# How to convert PDF in google drive to Text by google script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I am working on the code to convert PDF in google drive to Text.  And, I can convert PDF by below codes.  However, when I tried to specify the PDF in google drive by URL (e.g. var url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gs-WvPPPPPPP0-iaawwadafa--";).  The code doesn't work.

```
var url = "https://www.test.com/sites/g/files/xyz123.pdf";  
    // It works fine.  And, if changes to google drive URL, it doesn't work.  
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    // No error showed up at getBlob.

Logger.log(blob) // shows "Blob" after changes to google drive URL
Logger.log(blob.getName()) // shows "open.html" after changes to google drive URL
Logger.log(blob.getContentType()) // shows "text/html" after changes to google drive URL

var resource = {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()    
};

var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});
    // At above line, Error message "OCR is not supported for files of type text/html (line 64, file "Code")" showed. 

var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
var text = doc.getBody().getText();

return text;
```

I would like to convert PDF files in folder of google drive to TEXT one by one.

Comment: please be more specific then it doesn't work. Any errors? what happens instead of the wanted behavior

Comment: What happens if you use DriveApp to get the blob? i.e. `DriveApp.getFileById("id").getBlob()`

Comment: Thanks. "DriveApp.getFileByID("id").getBlob()" works !!